# How does LTE eNodeB set the Base Station output power?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, wireless-communication, lte

I'm interested into the power radiated out of an eNodeB (LTE/4G) radio base station: which parameters does this power depend on, if they are constant or relying on the environment...

All of this in order to be able to predict the rated power transmitted out of the BS antenna.

I've been seeking in the 3GPP technical requirements and sheets, but nothing conclusive about it until now, specificaly for LTE signals.

It shall differ from the others radio standards such as GSM or UMTS since LTE uses OFDM which implies multiple carriers instead of one. My guess is that those multiple carriers should in theory reduce the rated power per carrier.

I still have some certitudes about it, those being that the output power depends on the cell size, also that traffic-load, somehow, is taken into account (potential small cells may be deployed for capacity boost).